# How to track item's index in type list

Tags: vb.net, list

This may be a simple question, but I'm having a real mental block on it. I'm trying to track the index of a Report in my reportList (of Report type) when navigating forwards and backwards through the list.

I've done this one way by assigning the index of the selected item in a combobox. However I also need to do it directly from the list (already filled), with the only input of the user being the next and previous buttons.

Where I set the Report:

```
    If wantFixture = True Then
                ind = UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedIndex
            Else
                ind = reportList(0) 'index of item in reportList- 

'this doesn't work because reportList is of type Report, not integer  
            End If

reportList.Clear()
        reportList = retrieveReport()

        '*****General Information
        UC_Menu_Scout1.lblRptPosition.Text = reportList(ind).PositionPlayed
```

Where the next Report can be navigated to:

```
Private Sub btnNextPlayer_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextPlayer.Click
            'Moves to next item in playerList
            Dim x As Integer = cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedIndex
            If x = cmbSelectedPlayer.Items.Count - 1 Then
                x = 0
            Else
                x += 1
            End If

            cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedIndex = x

            lblNumberOfReports.Text = "Report: " & x + 1 & "/" & cmbSelectedPlayer.Items.Count

        End Sub
```

Comment: You could use `reportList` as the datasource for the CBO so there is no converting Selected anything to Index - SelectedItem will give you the Report selected.  Otherwise just iterate the collection in a for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried it with the for loop:                          For i As Integer = 0 To reportList.Count - 1
                ind = i
            Next                                                                                                     But how do I make this work with the Next button click?

Comment: that loop goes thru all of the reports.  I dont know how that factors into a Next button.  Maybe you could edit the question to make clearer *what* you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the current index and report in variables.

Class level variables:

```
Private curIndex As Integer = 0
Private curReport As Report = Nothing
```

Next button:

```
If Not curIndex = reportList.Count - 1 Then
  curIndex += 1
End If
curReport = reportList.ElementAt(curIndex)
```

Previous button:

```
 If Not curIndex = 0 Then
  curIndex -= 1
End If
curReport = reportList.ElementAt(curIndex)
```